# Styling a div only if another div exists in the parent div with css

Tags: html, css

I want to style a div only if a certain other div exists inside the parent. Just look at the following piece of code. The parent div is `'main'`, and inside this parent div there are two child divs, that is `"first"` and `"second"`. I want to style the div `"second"` only if the div `"first"` exists inside the parent div, that is `"main"`. It is possible that sometimes the `"first"` div is not inside the main div. Is it possible to do this with CSS?
Millions of thanks in advance.

```css
<div id="main">
            <div id="first"></div>
            ...some other divs...
            <div id="second"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `#main > #first + #second {...rules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to style `#second` if it is a *sibling* of `#first`
`+` is the *adjacent* sibling selector,
`~` is the *general* sibling selector.

Since you want to allow other divs in between — "...some other divs..." — you'll want the *general* sibling selector `~` not the *adjacent* sibling selector `+`.

```css
#main #first ~ #second {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="first">First (default black color)</div>
  <div>some</div>
  <div>other</div>
  <div>divs</div>
  <div id="second">Second (red)</div>
</div>
```

...and here's an example where `#first` doesn't appear

```css
#main #first ~ #second {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div id="main">
      <div id="not-first">First (default black color)</div>
      <div>some</div>
      <div>other</div>
      <div>divs</div>
      <div id="second">Second (red)</div>
    </div>
```

CSS-Tricks has a good article about [Child and Sibling Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)